# Blend mode ‘Darken’ in Mix RGB node is showing different color

Tags: node-editor

I'm following this tutorial where he explains how the Mix RGB node works, and to better understand, I'm trying to replicate his steps. What I don't understand is why I'm not getting the same color as him despite having the same settings? My only thought is that I'm doing something fundamentally wrong, or perhaps the blend modes of the Mix RGB node have been updated? I'm hoping someone can help me figure this out.

Link with timestamp: https://youtu.be/91UDQnrZMqA?t=196

[image]Printscreen:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've plugged your *Mix Color* into a *Principlded BSDF*, while in the tuto he probably plugs it directly into the *Output*, the *Principled BSDF* will add some effects, mainly specularity (the surface reflects the lights and environment and therefore the color looks brighter than you think), lower it down to 0 and you'll have the same as in the video.

Comment: Oh, of course! Thank you!